# Python class: The data is somehow lost

Tags: python, class, oop, praw

I am trying to define a Python class which analyzes subreddit data via the [praw](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package.

I am fairly experienced with OOP in C++, but have not had much experience with OOP in Python. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import praw
class SubRedditAnalyzer:

    def __init__(self, reddit_session, name='dataisbeautiful'):
        self.name = name # subreddit name
        self.reddit_session = reddit_session # assign the reddit session
        self.subreddit = self.reddit_session.get_subreddit(self.name) # create the subreddit object
        self.timeframe = 'day'
        self.max_post_count = 10
        self.submissions = self.subreddit.get_top_from_hour(limit=10)

    def __del__(self):
        class_name = self.__class__.__name__
        print class_name, "destroyed"

    def get_top_submissions(self, max_post_count):

        timeframe = self.timeframe

        if (timeframe == 'hour'):
            self.submissions = self.subreddit.get_top_from_hour(limit= max_post_count)
        elif (timeframe == 'day'):
            self.submissions = self.subreddit.get_top_from_day(limit= max_post_count)
        elif (timeframe == 'week'):
            self.submissions = self.subreddit.get_top_from_week(limit= max_post_count)
        elif (timeframe == 'month'):
            self.submissions = self.subreddit.get_top_from_month(limit= max_post_count)
        elif (timeframe == 'year'):
            self.submissions = self.subreddit.get_top_from_year(limit= max_post_count)
        elif (timeframe == 'all'):
            self.submissions = self.subreddit.get_top_from_all(limit= max_post_count)

    def combine_titles(self):
        titles = ""
        for submission in self.submissions:
            titles += submission.title
        self.titles = titles 

    def display_titles(self):
        counter = 1
        ya = self.submissions
        for sub in self.submissions:
            sc = sub.score
            ti = sub.title
            print('T%d- [%d] %s \n' %(counter,sc,ti))
            counter += 1

def main():
   r = praw.Reddit('Request to fetch data by user')
   sr = SubRedditAnalyzer(r, 'dataisbeautiful')
   sr.get_top_submissions(15) # top 15 from reddit
   sr.combine_titles()        # combine the top titles    
   sr.display_titles()        # display all the titles 

main()
```

For some unknown (to me) reason, it seems that the data in class 'sr' is lost after calling:

```
sr.combine_titles()
```

When I try to call this method, the data in class is empty:

```
sr.display_titles()
```

In fact, I do see the message that the class is destroyed:

**SubRedditAnalyzer destroyed**

What is it that I am doing wrong? 
In advance, thanks for your attention.

Comment: I don't know `praw`, but your code looks ok to me & I can't see any obvious reason why the `__del__` method would be called prematurely.

Comment: Surely the class is destroyed at the end of your main() method, which is what you should expect, no?

Comment: @PM2Ring: Thanks for your comment. Since I have not had experience with classes in Python, I was not sure whether or not it is something I am doing wrong. FYI, without any classes, this code works fine. Do you have any suggestions as to how I could track the issue down? Thanks.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: The class does not display the titles. I played around a bit and it seems that after calling `sr.combine_titles()` the data (or reference to class data) is somehow lost.

Comment: Well see my answer for that. I was just addressing your confusion over the calling of `__del__`, which appears to be happening exactly where it would be expected to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `self.submissions` may be an iterable but not a collection (e.g. a list). [The docs](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/code_overview.html?highlight=get_top_from_hour#praw.__init__.BaseReddit.get_content) call `get_top_from_hour()` a *generator* method (although they state also that what is returned is a list...). If it is indeed a [generator method](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), the result can be iterated over only once. All other attempts at iteration will fail silently (the loop in `display_titles()` executes nothing).

So, the solution would be:

```
self.submissions = list(self.subreddit.get_top_from_hour(limit=10))
```

in `__init__()` to convert an iterable into a permanent collection (list) that can be iterated over multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

According to the PRAW docs, [`get_content`](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/code_overview.html#praw.__init__.BaseReddit.get_content) and its associated methods like `get_top_from_hour` return a *generator*. A generator can only be iterated once, which you do in `combine_titles`. After that iteration, the generator is exhausted and cannot be iterated again.

You could presumably convert the submissions to a list when you get them in `__init__`:

```
self.submissions = list(self.subreddit.get_top_from_hour(limit=10))
```

Comment: Totally makes sense now. Thanks for your help Daniel.